# How to get first record of top command in linux?

Tags: linux

How to get first record of top command in linux by using below line of code

```
$ top -b|tee aorpprkd004.out| grep 'Cpu(s): | head -1'
```

Above is not working

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
grep 'Cpu(s): | head -1'
```

Should probably be this:

```
grep 'Cpu(s):' | head -1
```

Note the quotes.

Comment: used your suggesstion but still unable to get the expected results.

Comment: @VaibhavSoni: if you want people to help you,  you need to be a lot more explicit about what you think is wrong.  Try disassembling your pipeline and seeing what the output is at every stage.  It's not very pleasant to debug when you say "unable to get the expected results."  You haven't even told us what the expected results are.

Answer (score 2):

First up, you need to move the quotes since you *don't* want to be searching for the head command in the output. The text you're looking for is simply `Cpu(s):` with the output filtered through `head`.

Secondly, batch mode by default runs forever. If you're only going to be getting the first one anyway (as per your `head -1` filter), you may as well explicitly limit it with the `-n` option so that it exits immediately it's done that:

```
$  top -b -n1 | tee aorpprkd004.out | grep 'Cpu(s):'
Cpu(s):   2.0% user,   2.5% system,   0.0% nice,  95.5% idle
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with little change you can do it,

```
top -b|tee aorpprkd004.out| grep 'Cpu'
```